# Show files from ftp server in html gallery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ftp

I'm trying to achieve dynamic image loading from FTP server, but I have no clue how to make it work.

What I need is a PHP script which would pull images from my ftp server and create the HTML structure of this images with the paths and extension of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the PHP [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

I would have a new php file image_get.php.

With contents something like this:

```
<?php
$directory = "images/gallery";
foreach (glob($directory."/*.png") as $image) {
    echo '<a href="'.$image .'"><img src="'.$image .'"></a>';
}
?>
```

Then an ajax call the image_get.php file like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('image_get.php').done(function(data){
         $("#images").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in body of your html page have a div tag with an id equal to `images`.
You will have to make some changes to add classes to elements and to get all images, atm the `glob()` function is just returning all files in the directory with a extension of `.png`.

Ref:

PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I'll make some changes to run it ,, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this script:
http://www.ubergallery.net/